# Displaying file content with bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script (display) that will allow me to access a directory, list the files, and then display the content of all of the files. So far I am able to access the directory and list the files.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Check for folder name
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
  echo " Usage: count [folder name]"
  exit 1
fi

#Check if it is a directory
if [ ! -d "$1" ]; then 
  echo "Not a valid directory"
  exit 2
fi

#Look at the directory 
target=$1
echo "In Folder: $target"  
for entry in `ls $target`; do
  echo $entry 
done
```

So if I use the command ./display [directory] it will list the files. I want to display the contents of all of the files as well but I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Q: What exactly do you mean by "display"? You can [cat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) a text file to your console window.  But the shell is command-line oriented: it wouldn't necessarily "know" how to render a .jpg image or a .pdf document.

Comment: @paulsm4 I want use a shell script that will cat all of the text files in my directory.

Comment: Start by running your script through https://shellcheck.net and fixing the issues it points out.

Comment: `cd "$1" || exit; for file in *; do [[ -f $file ]] && cat "./$file"; done`. That should work if all files are text files in the directory. Otherwise your terminal will be filled up with garbage.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` to find files. Use `less` to display files interactively or `cat` otherwise.

```
find "$target" -type f -exec less {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

I thin a loop similar to your "look at the directory" loop would suffice, but using the `cat` command instead of `ls`

Comment: Both are the wrong way. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001